# Calculate the luminosity distance in terms of redshift and the scale factor

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Suppose you are in a spatially flat universe with a single parameter of the equation of state, $w$. Now for $w\neq -\frac{1}{3}$ calculate the luminosity distance in terms of redshift ($z$) and $w$.
Consider that the scale factor is
$$a(t)=(\frac{t}{t_0})^{\frac{1+3w}{3+3w}}$$
P.S. I am really unsure of how to solve this problem, I'm truly lost and I have no idea on how to begin. Any help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: Well, first you need an equation for the luminosity distance. In there you'll find the comoving distance. And you have to calculate the comoving distance by taking an integral over $dt$.

Comment: Solved the problem or need help ?